# Set ImageView orientation directly in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

I understand that I can rotate an `ImageView` in Android by

```
matrix.postRotate(finalOrientation - initOrientation, width, height);
```

But I want to **set it as `finalOrientation` directly** instead of rotating it by the difference, `finalOrientation - initOrientation`.

So I am expecting something like:

```
matrix.setOrientation(finalOrientation);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what is the need for orientation you can do that in rotation itself

Comment: can you give an example.. using some real values..

Answer (score 3):

Perfect! thanks @Bette Devine! 
I made a function just for convenience.

```
public Bitmap rotateBmp(Bitmap bmp){
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    //set image rotation value to 90 degrees in matrix.
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    //supply the original width and height, if you don't want to change the height and width of bitmap.
    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    return bmp;
}
```

I had to do this with a downsized image. I got a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" when I tried to do this with a full size image. : (

Answer (score 1):

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
//set image rotation value to 90 degrees in matrix.
matrix.postRotate(90);
//supply the original width and height, if you don't want to change the height and width of bitmap.
Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, matrix, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following link:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/handling_rotation/